# onSaveInstanceState() does not work when the screen is rotated

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Possible, my code is correct, but method onSaveInstanceState() does not work when the screen is rotated. The data does not save after activity destroy (onDestroy() worked). However, the method works after methods onPause() and onStop(). There is one element on activity - textView, and I write text when the methods are worked. There is the error? Thank you in advance.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
           textView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("saveInstance"));
        }

        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onCreate() worked");
        textView.append("onCreate() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onStart() worked");
        textView.append("onStart() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onResume() worked");
        textView.append("onResume() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onRestart() worked");
        textView.append("onRestart() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onPause() worked");
        textView.append("onPause() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onStop() worked");
        textView.append("onStop() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onDestroy() worked");
        textView.append("onDestroy() worked\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i("lifecycle show", "onSaveInstanceState() worked");
        textView.append("onSaveInstanceState() worked\n");
        outState.putString("savedInstance", textView.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong tag. You put string using "savedInstance" as tag, then get string by tag "saveInstance".

Comment: My God... Thank You so much. It is funny but I'm very ashamed. =)